# jQuery toggle() function doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: jquery

I have a content box in my WordPress Template and a button at the bottom of it. In the middle of the box there are it an unordered list that should open up once the button it clicked. Once the button is clicked again the list closes again. I added a bit more code to change the button text based on the state and since then the toggle doesn't work on iPhone. Desktop works just fine.

jQuery code:

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#ul1").hide();
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
         $("#ul1").toggle();
$(this).text(function(i, v){
               return v === 'MORE' ? 'LESS' : 'MORE';
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML for the content box:

```
<div class="x-column x-sm benefitsColumn x-1-3" style="padding: 0;">
    <div class="x-text cs-ta-center benefitsHeader">
        <div id="b1"></div>
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="x-text cs-ta-left">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="x-text cs-ta-left">
        <ul id="ul1" class="bullets2">
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a id="btn1" class="x-btn reasonsButton x-btn-flat x-btn-rounded x-btn-large" href="#b1" data-options="thumbnail: ''">MORE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried: 1. suppressing the default anchor behavior with `e.preventDefault()` or 2. adding `click` and `touch` via the `.on()`- event handler?

Comment: @empiric My jQuery knowledge is somewhat limited so I am not quite sure what those are.

Comment: see here: [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), [touch-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)